# Google Sheets: How to enter same text across cells in a column with arrayformula?

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

Instead of copy/paste same number across cells, I'm trying to utilize arrayformula in google sheets, if it's possible.  These didn't work, getting an error message saying "Circular dependency detected. To resolve with iterative calculation, see File > Settings.".

- =arrayformula(A3:A10="1.2%")
- =arrayformula(A3:A10=C1): "1.2%" is entered in C1 cell'

Any suggestion?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(A3:A10),C1))
```

OR

```
=INDEX(SEQUENCE(ROWS(A3:A10),1,1,0)*C1)
```

- 

[image]

Comment: Oh, what a magic!   BTW, the last two formula are working well, while the first one didn't work on my computer.  Thank you!